# How to read each line of a QPlainTextEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, timer, webkit, webview

I want to make a program where I take each line of QPlainTextEdit and send it to a WebView which will load those urls. I don't need to check the URL's because the system makes it like that

```
http://someurl.com/ + each line of the QPlainTextEdit
```

I have few ideas which I don't know how to use:

1. Use a foreach loop which will make its self wait 5 seconds to loop again
2. Make a QTimer to wait like 5 seconds and tick with an integer and when the integer hits the number of lines it will stop

And all of that will be done on every 4 hours by waiting with another timer.

Comment: "I want to make a program where I take each line of QPlainTextEdit and send it to a WebView which will load those urls. " You don't read what i've typed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need the contents of the `QPlainTextEdit`. Get them and split them using the new line separator to get a list of `QStrings` each representing a line.

```
QString plainTextEditContents = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText()
QStringList lines = plainTextEditContents.split("\n");
```

The easiest way to process the lines is to use a `QTimer` and store somewhere the current index in the list.

```
// Start the timer
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processLine()));
timer->start(5000);
```

Now the slot is called whenever the timer is triggered. It just gets the current line and you do it whatever you want.

```
void processLine(){
   // This is the current index in the string list. If we have reached the end
   // then we stop the timer.
   currentIndex ++;

   if (currentIndex == lines.count())
   {
       timer.stop();
       currentIndex = 0; 
       return;
   }

   QString currentLine = lines[currentIndex];
   doSomethingWithTheLine(currentLine); 
}
```

Similarly do the same with the 4h timer.